# PFX import always gives Incorrect password error

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, self-signed

I tried to generate a private key and certificate using [OpenSSL v3.0.1](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) on  x64 using the command:

```
"C:\Program Files\OpenSSL\bin\openssl.exe" req -x509 -sha256 -days 7300 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout ProductPrivate.key -out ProductCertificate.crt
```

Then I try to package the key and certificate into a single PFX file using the command:

```
"C:\Program Files\OpenSSL\bin\openssl.exe" pkcs12 -export -out KeyPackage.pfx -inkey ProductPrivate.key -in ProductCertificate.crt -passout pass:superevil -passin pass:secret
```

Here is the actual screenshot, you can see all steps completes successfully and that you can see the password I set it up with.

[image]

I verified that all three files are created:

[image]

Next I took the pfx and try to import it into a certificate store of couple of machines, however everywhere I tried, I got the same password incorrect error.  I used this same instruction 5 - 6 years ago and everything worked so I don't know what changed? do you happen to know?

The screen below proof that I have the right password for the pfx entered.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, this is only issue if I use openssl v. 3.0.1.  I test the same steps against openssl 1.1 and the import works.

Answer (score 1):

Add flag `-certpbe PBE-SHA1-3DES -keypbe PBE-SHA1-3DES` in your `openssl3.X` command.