# System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Invalid provider type specified. Problem with recreating and importing the .pfx

Tags: iis, openssl, certificate, saml-2.0, windows-server-2016

I'm experiencing a known issue when installing a certificate on a Windows Server 2016, resulting in the following exception: *System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Invalid provider type specified.* and no private keys being available for the installed certificate. I then tried to recreate a new pfx based on the old pfx, with the help from this post:

["Invalid provider type specified" CryptographicException when trying to load private key of certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581811/invalid-provider-type-specified-cryptographicexception-when-trying-to-load-pri)

And the following commands:

```
OpenSSL pkcs12 -in "cert_name.p12" -nokeys -out "cert_name.cer" -passin "pass:123456"

OpenSSL pkcs12 -in "cert_name.p12" -nocerts -out "cert_name.pem" -passin "pass:123456" -passout "pass:123456"

OpenSSL rsa -inform PEM -in "cert_name.pem" -out "cert_name.rsa" -passin "pass:123456" -passout "pass:123456"

OpenSSL pkcs12 -export -in "cert_name.cer" -inkey "cert_name.rsa" -out "cert_name_converted.p12" -passin "pass:123456" -passout "pass:123456"
```

However, when trying to install/import the `cert_name_converted.p12`, with the password mentioned in the "`-passout`"-parameter, the password seems to be incorrect.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btRp6.png)

Can anyone advise what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Is your problem solved? Any progress on this issue? Looking forward to your reply, thank you！

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, when you import this .pfx file to a Windows server, you receive an error after entering the password – "The password you entered is incorrect". This error is very misleading.

Usually the cause of this error is the version of OpenSSL you used to generate the certificate. This is because Windows Server supports certificates generated using OpenSSL 1.1.1 or lower. You can check the version of OpenSSL by opening OpenSSL command prompt and typing the following command:

```
openssl version
```

If your OpenSSL is a higher version, you can download OpenSSL 1.1.1 [from this link](https://www.openssl.org/source/). After installing OpenSSL 1.1.1, regenerate the .pfx file. This time when you import the file into the Windows server it will work fine.

similar threads:

["The password you entered is incorrect" when importing .pfx files to Windows certificate store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69343254/the-password-you-entered-is-incorrect-when-importing-pfx-files-to-windows-cer)

[PFX import always gives Incorrect password error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70869582/pfx-import-always-gives-incorrect-password-error)